# loop em matriz de correlação em R

Tags: r

Tenho tentado aprender sobre loops e funções em R. Assim me dispus à seguinte situação:
Tenho uma matriz de correlação par a par:

```
dados<-matrix(rnorm(100),5,5)
colnames(dados)<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
rownames(dados)<-c('A','B','C','D','E')
dados
cor<-cor(dados)
```

Quero usar condições de loop e if para obter apenas as combinações das variáveis com valores > 0.5 do objeto cor. Entretando, não consigo encontrar uma modo para percorrer par a par as linhas e colunas da minha matrix.

Tenho tentado o seguinte código:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cor)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(cor)){
    # comando para comparar par a par
    if (cor[i,j]>0.5){
      #retornar um nova matrix com variável e valor > 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar esses comandos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um jeito fácil é utilizar a função `melt` do pacote `reshape2`, como foi explicado [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666533/finding-row-column-names-from-a-correlation-matrix-values) (em inglês).

#### código:

```
install.packages("reshape2")             # Caso você não tenha instalado o pacote ainda
library(reshape2)

set.seed(0101)
dados <- matrix(rnorm(100),5,5)
colnames(dados) <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
rownames(dados) <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
CorMatrix <- cor(dados)                    # Tente usar nomes de variáveis que não sejam 
                                           # também nome de função

CM <- corMatrix                            # Copiando sua matriz
CM[lower.tri(CM, diag = TRUE)] <- NA       # Removendo as correlações repetidas e a diagonal
rownames(resultados) <- NULL               # (não necessário) limpando os nomes das linhas
resultado <- subset(                      # Filtra as linhas que possuem o valor de correlação
    melt(CM, na.rm=T),                     # maior do que você queira (0.5 no caso)
    value > 0.5)
```

#### resultado:

```
>resultado
   Var1  Var2   value
1   C     D    0.5215197
```

Uma dica referente ao seu código, não utilize o nome de uma função como nome de variável, como foi o caso da matrix `cor`.

Answer (score 1):

Pressupondo que você queira que usar loops (para treinar ou por outra razão, porque neste caso não é preciso usar loops), você pode aramazenar os resultados em uma lista.

Recriando seus dados (com `set.seed()` para reproducibilidade):

```
set.seed(10)
dados <- matrix(rnorm(100),5,5)
colnames(dados) <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
rownames(dados) <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
cor <- cor(dados)
```

Percorrendo o loop e salvando resultados em uma lista:

```
# lista para armazenar resultado
resultados <- list()

for (i in 1:nrow(cor)){
  for (j in 1:ncol(cor)){
    if (cor[i,j]>0.5){
      # armazena no primeiro nível a linha e no segundo nível a coluna
      resultados[[rownames(cor)[i]]][[colnames(cor)[j]]] <- cor[i,j]
    }
  }
}

resultados
$A
        A         C 
1.0000000 0.7764006 

$B
       B        E 
1.000000 0.912793 

$C
        A         C 
0.7764006 1.0000000 

$D
D 
1 

$E
       B        E 
0.912793 1.000000
```

Com a lista em mãos você pode arrumar os dados da forma como quiser. Por exemplo, a forma mais simples de transformar em um vetor é com `unlist()`.

```
unlist(resultados)

     A.A       A.C       B.B       B.E       C.A       C.C       D.D       E.B       E.E 
1.0000000 0.7764006 1.0000000 0.9127930 0.7764006 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9127930 1.0000000
```

Mas vale lembrar que você não precisa usar loops neste caso. Por exemplo, uma forma de obter o mesmo resultado acima seria:

```
indices <- which(cor > 0.5, arr.ind = TRUE)
res <- setNames(cor[indices], paste(colnames(cor)[indices[,2]], rownames(cor)[indices[,1]], sep = "."))
res
     A.A       A.C       B.B       B.E       C.A       C.C       D.D       E.B       E.E 
1.0000000 0.7764006 1.0000000 0.9127930 0.7764006 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.9127930 1.0000000
```